# How to override a contrib module's FieldType plugin?

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to override a FieldType plugin provided by the Field Encrypt module:

```
class EncryptedFieldStorageItem extends FieldItemBase {
```

I created my own class, `MyModuleEncryptedFieldStorageItem`, and put it in `my_module/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/MyModuleEncryptedFieldStorageItem.php`.

Now I need to inform Drupal that I want to override the Field Encrypt module's `EncryptedFieldStorageItem` class with my `MyModuleEncryptedFieldStorageItem` class, right?  In the past, I've done this using `MyModuleServiceProvider` to set the class, but here, I don't want to override the field type plugin class; I want to override the class of one specific plugin.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FieldType plugin manager provides an alter hook `mymodule_field_info_alter()`.

Example from the core language module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_info_alter().
 */
function language_field_info_alter(&$info) {
  // Change the default behavior of language field.
  $info['language']['class'] = '\Drupal\language\DefaultLanguageItem';
}
```

Comment: For anyone specifically trying to change the field Encrypt module's class, note that it isn't always the module's name.  In this case, it's `$info['encrypted_field_storage']['class']`.

Comment: Yes, this is a coincidence that the language module is changing the language field. You find the plugin's ID in the class annotations, in this example  `* @FieldType(id = "language" ...` in /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/Plugin/Field/FieldType/LanguageItem.php.